# GnuPG still 1.4.16 after 2.1.11 installation

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, encryption, gnupg

I have followed the steps in an [tutorial to install GnuPG 2.1.11](https://github.com/mattrude/pgpkeyserver/blob/master/doc/build-gnupg2.md) (even found an error with libgpg-error version, but corrected it). Even so, when I do a `gpg --version`, the system response is:

```
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.16
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

When I open my Enigmail Firefox extension (the reason I installed GnuPG 2.1.11) it tells me that I still have GnuPG 1.4.16, and that I need 2.1.11 to use Enigmail.

Did I miss something? The installation ocurred without errors. Why my Ubuntu 14.04 don't recognize 2.1.11 GnuPG installation? Or there's a better way to do the installation?

Comment: Try `gpg2 --version`. ;)

Comment: You solve that right! After I installed gpg2, my Enigmail just recognize it. Many thanks!

Comment: So what was the problem exactly, you did not have the package `gnupg2` installed?

Comment: The link you give is for compiling GnuPG from source, this is not needed since it is in the repositories...

Comment: The problem: I was installing `gnupg2` in my system and checking `gnupg` version. =\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### About GnuPG Versions

There are multiple branches of GnuPG, all under support and receiving updates. GnuPG 1.4 is the legacy version with a different architecture (monolithic vs. the more modular approach of the other versions), GnuPG 2.0 considered "stable" and GnuPG 2.1 "modern" with added elliptic-curve cryptography. Soon (which can be easily months from now in the GnuPG release history), GnuPG 2.2 will inherit GnuPG 2.0's "stable" tag.

### Don't Build GnuPG on Your Own

This seems like an issue with the installation location not being on your `$PATH`, or being there at the wrong location.

Anyway: do not build GnuPG on your own, if you're not very sure about what you're doing and especially know how to verify the package's signatures, know how to fix issues with your whole system and watch the project's mailing list for security notifications. GnuPG is deeply integrated with Ubuntu, especially in the package management/software center, and you can easily mess up your whole system!

### Installing GnuPG 2 from the Ubuntu Repositories

Ubuntu 14.04 does not ship GnuPG 2.1 yet, but does so with GnuPG 2.0 (which should be fine, if you're not after elliptic curve cryptography, which is not yet widely spread in OpenPGP, anyway). You can easily install it through

```
apt-get install gnupg2
```

[Ubuntu 16.04 will already ship GnuPG 2.1 under this package name](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&searchon=names&keywords=gnupg2) when released this month.

Comment: 2.1 has some other features besides ECC. In any case, still not available as a Trusty package.